# applying the DRY principles in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Just taking a use case for this instance. I'm compiling a `c++` file, and sometimes, I'd like to compile without `debugging symbols` i.e. the `-g` enabled and sometimes I would like to enable it.

So, I thought of just making two targets in which  the second target would reassign a make variable(is it possible) and change the compiling options. I wonder if such a behaviour is possible to achieve with makefiles?

Below is some pseudocode demo and the user enters `make first@bg` into the command line:

```
gpp = g++ -std=c++17

first: hello.cpp
    $(gpp) hello.cpp -o $@
    #/* some other recipes, assuming the list is really long*/

first@bg: main.o
    gpp = g++ -g -std=c++17 
    execute_all_recipe_of_first_target_which_is_really_long_to_copy()  

main.o: main.cpp
    $(gpp) main.cpp -c -o main.o #the value of gpp should'd also changed here since first@bg executed
```

If it is possible please provide me with the actual syntax for the demonstrated behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
first@bg: gpp += -g
first@bg: first
```

Note that it's more idiomatic to define `CXX=g++` and `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17` and then tweak `CXXFLAGS`, and use `make DEBUG=1` for debug builds:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
  CXXFLAGS+=-g
endif
```

Then invoke the compiler as `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) hello.cpp -o $@` for example. See also [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html)

Comment: in your first block of code, can we assign variables in the `prerequisite` section? and in the second block of code, does the variable `DEBUG` have to be declared inside the `makefile` before we pass it via command line, in which case we'd have to give it a default or junk value?

Comment: Any make variable reference will expand to the empty string if it's not been defined.  So you don't have to predefine it if you don't want to.  I'm not sure what you mean by _the prerequisite section_, but the answer should link you to the documentation for target-specific variable assignments: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Comment: @MadScientist , the link says that the target specific variable only holds in it's recipe, does it mean it doesn't apply to another target listed in it's prerequisite section. (Make has the `target: prerequisite \t recipe` format which is the prerequisite I am talking about)

Comment: Your question is addressed directly in the documentation.  Please keep reading to the paragraph that starts _There is one more special feature ..._  And... feel free to test it!!  With makefiles in particular it's often much faster to just write a test and see what happens, than to ask a question and wait for someone to answer it :)